# Type is deducted successfully when is wrapped in method, but not when used in direct alias

Tags: c++, alias, template-meta-programming, deduction-guide

Code where type deduction is wrapped method

```
struct InterfaceOverriderFactory
{
    template <typename Interface>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Type<Interface>) const noexcept
    {
         return typename FunctionArguments::InvokeOperatorArguments<Interface>{};
    }
};
```

Alias(is used as deduction guide)

```
template <typename Interface, typename Code>
using IO = typename std::invoke_result_t<InterfaceOverriderFactory, Type<Interface>>::PushFront<Code>::PushFront<Interface>::WithT<InterfaceOverrider>;
```

Same code, but without wrapping it in method

```
template <typename Interface, typename Code>
using IO = typename FunctionArguments::InvokeOperatorArguments<Interface>::PushFront<Code>::PushFront<Interface>::WithT<InterfaceOverrider>;
```

Both code snippets are used in

```
template <typename ...Interfaces, typename ...Codes>
Strategy(std::pair<type::Type<Interfaces>, Codes>...) -> Strategy<type::IO<Interfaces, Codes>...>;
```

For code where type is deduced via method I've got `Strategy<SomeTypes...>`

For direct alias - `Strategy<>`

This code returns struct that is holding types, via template <typename... Args>

```
FunctionArguments::InvokeOperatorArguments<Interface>
```

So, I want to make code in paragraph "Same code, but without wrapping it in method" work or if it is not possible to know why

Comment: Could [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) be of help?

Comment: @Eljay If you mean replace std::invoke_result_t with std::invoke - it will not solve the problem. I want to get rid of InterfaceOverriderFactory.

For some reason code `FunctionArguments::InvokeOperatorArguments<Interface>` works differently  when used in method and alias